# Nginx failing to proxy a location

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx reverse proxy setup like so:

```
server {
listen 5000 default_server;
listen [::]:5000 default_server ipv6only=on;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
client_max_body_size 100m;
large_client_header_buffers 4 40k;
    server_name localhostsecure;
location / {
     proxy_pass https://app-address.com;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location /path/ {
    proxy_pass http://mypathaddress.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
}
```

The issue is that sometimes, the /path/ is not redirected and cause a timeout. There is no issue with the actual server and I can ping it from the nginx server, it's working. also, the root server continues to work. restarting nginx solves this problem, but I can't figure out why does this happen at all. anyone has this issue?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453388/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-504-gateway-timeout . Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The `http://mypathaddress.com` server is taking too long to respond at that point of time, and therefore nginx times out. This temporary exhaustion of resources doesn't prevent the server from replying to ping. The application software that generates the data for the request is failing.

You should check the logs of the application server.

Comment: That was the first thing that I was thinking but curl from within that nginx server returned fast and without a problem